# Javascript and Priority Queues in coding interviews

Tags: javascript, heap, priority-queue

One pretty big issue I've run into with JS is that it has no in built in priority queue unlike Java or Python (heapq).

I was just wondering in an interview situation, could you propose below solution and essentially 'pretend' that JS does indeed have a native Priority Queue structure:

https://leetcode.com/problems/merge-k-sorted-lists/discuss/10528/A-java-solution-based-on-Priority-Queue

Only asking because implementing a MinHeap is pretty complicated and not sure if I'll able to do it in a high stress environment.

Comment: Leetcode supports the datastructure-PQ give here: https://github.com/datastructures-js/priority-queue
You can also see my solution to the problem mentioned above here: https://leetcode.com/problems/merge-k-sorted-lists/discuss/1464427/javascript-minpriorityqueue-18-lines-code

Answer (score 2):

I think it's fair to assume you can use an npm library to make JavaScript have capabilities comparable to other languages.

[Google Closure Library](https://github.com/google/closure-library) has some useful structures implemented in JavaScript.

You can find `goog.structs.PriorityQueue` [here](https://github.com/google/closure-library/blob/master/closure/goog/structs/priorityqueue.js).

Facebook similarly has [fbjs](https://github.com/facebook/fbjs).

You can find their `Heap` implementation [here](https://github.com/facebook/fbjs/blob/master/packages/fbjs/src/struct/Heap.js).

Comment: Ok but do you think this would be acceptable in a whiteboarding situation to just have const heap = new PriorityQueue() ?

Comment: yep, you just need to know which operations it can perform (i.e. `insert()`, `remove()`, `peek()`, etc.)

Comment: Hope it help, feel free to ask your recruiter if you are still not sure. And good luck with the interviews!